# How to use Repository data in two different fragments

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-mvvm

I have FragmentA and FragmentAViewModel. FragmentAViewModel calls RepositoryA for getContactData(), which is a silent call without blocking the UI.

Now User Navigate to FragmentB which has FragmentBViewModel.  User needs the getContactData() response here in FragmentB.

I want to show loading progress in FragmentB until the data is available in RepositoryA. Once Data is avaiable in RepositoryA, i want to update the FragmentBViewModel and FragmentB .

How can do that.

NOTE:
I dont want to share the ViewModel since this is the small use case in whole feature.
I cannot use LiveData in Repository since i need Lifecycle owner to observe that.

Do i need to use RXAndroid or Broadcast for this ?

Comment: so, what's the point in all of this ? what's the point of doing the call in A if you need the data in B ? `I want to show loading progress in FragmentB until the data is available in RepositoryA` so why do it in A ?

Comment: I want that data in FragmentA too, but user may not be waiting for the data to load in FragmentA

Comment: can you not just share the same base activity then ? i suppose this would be too big of a refactor for you to do, best thing you can do then is probably make use of a database

Comment: Even with base fragment or activity, the instance of view model will be different. I don't think that will work.  I feel only way is Broadcast or RXAndroid. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: `Even with base fragment or activity, the instance of view model will be different` no ? that's not how sharing a vm works. how do you imagine Rxjava will solve this ?

Comment: I thought, In repository i can make the API result Observable using RX, then i can subscribe the same in the FragmentB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239697/discussion-between-yogesh-byndoor-and-a-local-nobody).

Answer (score 0):

The flow is a bit strange to me but it's totally doable.

If both pages are reference to the same data source, ex: same database via Room interface.

Then first page can trigger the fetch or update while the second page subscribe for the update and display it.